# How can I block a bunch of contacts in Skype on Linux?

Tags: linux, skype, blocking

I am using **Skype (Beta) 2.2.0.35** on my Ubuntu and after some trial I believe that it is not possible to block a whole bunch or group of contacts all in one move.

It would be a very handy feature: being able to block entire groups might avoid the need to create two different Skype accounts, which is the current trend seemingly.

In this link [here](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1300468) it seems that by selecting 2+ contacts one is able to block them all in a row. I guess this is valid for the Windows version however.

Can you confirm all of this?